# on iPad http url in src attribute of html 5 video tag is not working

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am not able to load the video using http url in src attribute of html 5 video tag on ***ipad***. Using both static and dynamic way to do this.However it is working fine on web browser.Here is my code:

```
Static:

     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
      <source src="http://xyz.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Dynamic:

```
function Video(){
           var html = "";
html += '<video id="someVideo" width="712" height="500" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">';
html += '<source src="http://xyz.mp4"  type="video/mp4" />';
html += '</video>';
$("#page33video2").html(html);

$('#someVideo').attr('src', 'http://xyz.mp4');
$('#someVideo')[0].load();


}
```

is there any way to load video using http url in src attribute of html 5 video tag?

Thanks in advance.
Vikas

Comment: Do u mean , you want to change the src of video dynamically ?

Please clear..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set src of video dynamically ,this is how you can do it

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 
<video id="video1" style="display: none;">
</video>
<script>
function playVideo() {
document.getElementById("video1").style.display = "inline";
myVid=document.getElementById("video1");
myVid.src= "http://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4";
myVid.play();
}
</script> 
<p onclick="playVideo();">Click me to play</p>
It may take some time to load Video
</body> 
</html>
```

:)

Comment: Hi Ameya, This code is not working for iPad. However it is working fine on web browser. I want set the src using http url on iPad.

Comment: @Vicky: - I have checked on my iPad its working fine .. but I have to wait for the video to download, after that you can again click the "Click me to play". to play video. Please tell if you are doing anything else.

Comment: Hi Ameya, I am try this in ePub3 and video is not loading by this method in iPad. Is there any restriction that ePub3 won't allow video tag to load the http url in src attribute?

Comment: Hi Ameya, I am try this in ePub3 and video is not loading by this method in iBooks of iPad. However it is working fine on "Readium". Is there any restriction that ePub3 won't allow video tag to load the http url in src attribute on iBooks?

Comment: I'm unaware of what is ePub3, but i searched and got that ePub3 should support audio and video tags ,as well it supports HTML5 ,CSS3. This link might help you http://idpf.org/epub/30/spec/epub30-overview.html
and go to multimedia part..

Comment: Also check this link ,where they say ePub3 supports video tag http://idpf.org/accessibility/guidelines/content/xhtml/video.php